# Use Path Dir from findstr command

Tags: batch-file, findstr

Trying to use the directory outputed by this line in my batch code.

```
findstr /M search_text "C:\Users\user\Desktop\*"
```

This output's a file directory.

```
"C:\Users\whatever\blabla"
```

I know I can just add >> and print it to a text file but I'd rather not go that route as I'm not sure how to pull the dir back into the command line in the first place. Is there somehow I can do like a Set=%k command to a variable for later use. Sorry I'm still very new to this. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
for /f %%i in ('findstr /m "search_text" "C:\Users\user\Desktop\*"') do set file=%%i
```

Then you have the output in the `%file%` variable.

Hope this helps.